# Changing email address to include plus sign prevents login

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login

Users are allowed to enter a plus sign in their email when updating email address in the profile section.  Users can validate this email address as the validation email will be correctly sent and clicking the link works.  The success message popup displays the email address but without the plus sign anymore, but this could just be a display thing I am not sure.  When the user tries to log in with the new email address, they will not be able to.

Seems like the email address is probably being modified upon persisting to the database or whatever backend this uses.  Possibly stripping the plus sign out, but I have no way to tell.

Example:
taco@gmail.com changing their email to taco+stackoverflow@gmail.com

Both are valid email addresses however the latter is impossible to log in with even after confirming the validation email.

Comment: _"Both are valid email addresses"_ AFAIK, a plus sign is not allowed as part of a Gmail email address and `foo+bar@gmail.com == foo@gmail.com`. Did you use Gmail just as an example?

Comment: @41686d6564 Not true it is allowed by gmail but does route as you indicate. See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26053/gmail-address-with-within-the-recipient-name

Comment: @41686d6564 If `foo+bar@gmail.com` equals `foo@gmail.com` then it *is* allowed as part of a gmail address. It is allowed as an alternative form. In any case, whether it is an alias or not shouldn't prevent someone using it as their account address on here, I would have thought.

Comment: Did you make the change under "EMAIL SETTINGS" → "Edit email settings" or under "SITE SETTINGS" → "My logins"? The first is unrelated to how you can log in and is used for emails you receive from Stack Inc.

Comment: I have an existing sock account with a + in its email address on gmail and that still works for logging in. Checked a few moments ago. So if something is changed then it must be in the sign-up/valdation phase. exisiting logins still work.

Comment: My bad guys, I changed it under EMAIL SETTINGS thinking that affected the login credentials.  Gmail has supported plus signs for over a decade so not sure why that is even a discussion at this point.